# Force ubuntu to access internet through proxy

Tags: proxy

I've set up a squid forward proxy to cache all internet requests. I have a public ip and opened port 3128. Now I just need to set my ubuntu server to force all internet connections to pass through this proxy, using the ip address and port number.

I know this command which will make ubuntu access the internet via a proxy, but I was told it wasn't permanent.

`export http_proxy="http://proxy.example.com:8080"`

Which command do I need to use to force ubuntu to go through this proxy regardless of reboots or sessions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing an export, put this in file `/etc/environment`:

```
http_proxy="http://proxy.example.com:8080"
https_proxy="http://proxy.example.com:8080"
ftp_proxy="http://proxy.example.com:8080"
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
HTTP_PROXY="http://proxy.example.com:8080"
HTTPS_PROXY="http://proxy.example.com:8080"
FTP_PROXY="http://proxy.example.com:8080"
NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
```

and reboot your server/vm.

Comment: do we still need to configure url in the browser to access internet through proxy ?? ( eq. inside  firefox settings > Configure proxies to access internet  )

Comment: this work fine!!! thanks

Answer (score 0):

fter some googling. i was able to fix this:

original:
`/etc/apt/apt.conf`

```
    Acquire::http::Proxy "xx.xx.xx.xx:8080";
```

modified apt.conf

`/etc/apt/apt.conf`

```
    Acquire::http::Proxy "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080";
```